# Possible to prove strong induction implies weak induction?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, induction

I have managed to formally prove (using my own system, not ZFC) that weak induction implies strong induction. I started with [Peano's 5 Axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html) for the natural numbers, constructed (in order) the addition function, partial ordering and strict ordering as sets of ordered n-tuples of $N$. Then I proved that strong induction will hold:

$\forall P\subset N: [0\in P ~\land~  \forall x \in N:[\forall y \in N:$
$[y \leq x \to y\in P]~ \to x+1 ~\in P] ~\to ~P=N]$

What about proving the converse? How can I show that the strong induction implies weak induction when I needed weak induction to construct addition and the orderings?

Comment: Shouldn't we know what system you're working in?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow The only axioms/rules of set theory that I used were for subsets, Cartesian  products and functions. I made no use of any recursion theorem.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment of @MichaelMorrow and think that you do need to elaborate a little bit on the system you used. Otherwise you will always have write why a given answer is missing things or doesn't work with the way you have things set up. (as is already the case the the current 2 answers) One comment I think I can already make is: If you want to take strong instead of weak induction as an axiom, you will probably need to add axioms about the ordering. And you do need the ordering already inside of your theory at this point, because it is needed to state strong induction.

Answer (score 0):

[rewritten in response to the OP's comment]

You don't need addition to state strong induction, if you have succession; but you do need order.

Two notions (untested):

- Define order independently of addition, as $a \leq b$ if and only if $b$ is contained in the closure of $\{a\}$ under succession.
- Replace the Peano axioms with the requirements that the set of natural numbers is non-empty and well ordered and satisfies an induction axiom, either strong or weak induction. Then prove the equivalence of the Peano axioms, the weak-induction version of the new axioms, and the strong-induction version.

[Original answer follows.]

*How can I show that the strong induction implies weak induction?*

You don't.  Axiom 5 of the Peano axioms (in the version you reference) just is weak induction.

Comment: I think the idea is to start with axioms 1-4 and assume strong induction holds and then show that weak induction must also hold.

Comment: Then maybe I should delete my answer; but that would wipe your comment; so I'll edit it instead.